# Before trying to delete asset, delete its children, using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to delete an asset in Earth Engine using the Java API. When I try to delete the asset, I get the error message:

> Before trying to delete an asset, delete its children: projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/[...]

The problem is that the children asset seems to be the same asset, with a different path (projects/earthengine-legacy/assets)!

As an example, I try to delete `users/myName/assetAAA`, and EE wants me to delete `projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/myName/assetAAA`, which seems exactly the same?
I even tried to use the function `ee.data.deleteAsset()`, specifying the full path, as in `ee.data.deleteAsset("projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/myName/assetAAA")` and still get the same error, that I should delete the asset itself.

What can I do to avoid this problem? What is exactly an asset *child*?

Illustration:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that the asset I was trying to delete is an ImageCollection! To delete it, one needs first to delete each image individually before deleting the ImageCollection.

To do so in the Java GUI:

1. Click on the asset details
2. Go to Images, delete each image (trash icon)
3. Then use the *Delete* button

Alternatively, if one uses the `earthengine` command line, one needs to pass the `recursive` argument to `rm`:

```
earthengine rm --recursive collection_id
```